# How to sum the columns and add it to the last row of column in a datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am new to winforms. I am just creating a score card application.
There will be n number of columns and n of rows. when the user changes the value of any cell, it should calculate the total of that column in the last cell/row of the column. I am using datagridview. which is that event that i need to fire on changing the value of cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your code to the [`CellEndEdit event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellendedit.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You will want to listen for the [CellValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged.aspx) event.  The [DataGridViewCellEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs.aspx) will have the [ColumnIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs.columnindex.aspx) that was updated so you know which column to re-add.