# How to sum column at the end of the datagridview

Tags: c#

I want to sum column at the end of my `DataGridView` as shown here:

[image]

```
      column1 | column2  |column3|  column3   |
      --------+----------+-------+------------|
      1       | 2        |    3  |     4      |
     ---------+----------+-------+------------|
      2       |  4       |     7 |      9     |
--------------+----------+-------+------------|
total 3        6           10         13
-----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing your latest code?

Comment: you have 4 question history. no comment, no accepted answers. show some respect to answers of your question

Comment: i dont mean last code

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820804/how-to-sum-the-columns-and-add-it-to-the-last-row-of-column-in-a-datagridview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the Total in footer of gridview :

```
 decimal total = dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(row => row.Field<decimal>("Amount"));
                    GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[1].Text = "Total";
                    GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[1].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
                    GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[2].Text = total.ToString("N2");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DataBound` event, it's firing  after all rows were databound, `Amount` sum i added to label. Label can be added in footer as `Total`:

```
protected void GridDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView gridView = (GridView)sender;
    DataTable dt= (DataTable)gridView .DataSource;
    decimal sum= dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("Amount"));
    totalLabel.Text = sum.ToString();
}
```

or add sum as last row

```
protected void GridDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 GridView gridView = (GridView)sender;
 DataTable dt = (DataTable)gridView.DataSource;
 decimal sum =  dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("Amount"));
 var newRow = dt.NewRow();
 newRow["Name"] = "Total";
 newRow["Amount"] = sum.ToString();
 dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
```